# Redirect ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[image: Error Message when adding redirect to handleSubmit]I'm trying to figure out how to redirect to a submit confirmation page when someone presses submit on the form. The form is connected to the server in backend and will send an email when the submit button is pressed. If I add an href to the button, the email is not sent. I tried adding a redirect in the end of the handleSubmit function, that gave an error in the screenshot below. Here is my code. Please help me do this!

Thank you!

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Contact.css";
import { 
  BrowserRouter as Router, 
  Route,
  Switch, 
  Redirect 
} from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

export default function ContactForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const firstName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    const lastName = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const message = document.getElementById("message").value;

    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/api/form",
      data: {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email,
        message: message
      }
    });
    document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect to="/submit"/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  };

  return (
    <div
      id="contact"
      className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid min-vh-100 m-0"
    >
      <div className="container container-fluid text-center ">
        <h1> Contact Me </h1>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            marginBottom: "20px",
          }}
        >
          <form
            onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}
            className="contact-form"
            id="contact-form"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              padding: "25px",
              borderRadius: "10px"
            }}
          >
            <TextField
              required
              label="First Name"
              type="text"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              id="firstname"
              placeholder="First name"
            />
            <TextField
              required
              label="Last Name"
              type="text"
              id="lastname"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              placeholder="Last Name"
            />
            <TextField
              required
              label="Email Address"
              type="email"
              id="email"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              placeholder="Email Address"
            />
            <TextField
              required
              label="Message"
              type="text-area"
              id="message"
              multiline
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              placeholder="Message"
            />
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center"
              }}
            >
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                type="submit"
                style={{ width: "50%", marginTop: "25px" }}
                className={classes.button}
                endIcon={<SendIcon />}
              >
                Send Message
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `Redirect` component, you can make use of `useHistory` and do the following:

```
...
import { 
  BrowserRouter as Router, 
  Route,
  Switch, 
  useHistory 
} from "react-router-dom";
...

export default function ContactForm() {
  const history = useHistory()
  ...

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    ...
    history.replace('/submit')
    // or you can use history.push('/submit')
  };

  ...
}
```

This method is a lot cleaner and will allow you to change the history programmatically rather than attempting to render a `Redirect` component.